# Twitter login button fail to login

Tags: ios, twitter

I downloaded some sample code about twitter login code and run it in Xcode, when I run the App, a button appeared in the screen, and when I click it, I cannot login twitter successfully, the code goes to the else path, the code associated with the button is like below:

```
@IBAction func signInWithTwitter(sender: UIButton) {
    Twitter.sharedInstance().logInWithCompletion { session, error in
        if session != nil {
            // Navigate to the main app screen to select a theme.
            self.navigateToMainAppScreen()

            // Tie crashes to a Twitter user ID and username in Crashlytics.
            Crashlytics.sharedInstance().setUserIdentifier(session!.userID)
            Crashlytics.sharedInstance().setUserName(session!.userName)

            // Log Answers Custom Event.
            Answers.logLoginWithMethod("Twitter", success: true, customAttributes: ["User ID": session!.userID])
        } else {
            // Log Answers Custom Event.
            Answers.logLoginWithMethod("Twitter", success: false, customAttributes: ["Error": error!.localizedDescription])
        }
    }
}
```

Has anyone faced this problem? Who can help me out, thanks in advance.

Comment: What error does it show?  (i.e. `error!.localizedDescription`)

Comment: Request failed: unauthorized (401)

Comment: @PhillipMills, and also the detail error is:error NSError? domain: "TwitterAPIErrorDomain" - code: 32 0x00007fd26b0271d0
[1] (null) "NSLocalizedDescription" : "Request failed: unauthorized (401)  [0] (null) "NSErrorFailingURLKey" : "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"
[2] (null) "NSLocalizedFailureReason" : "Twitter API error : Could not authenticate you. (code 32)"